# Making a GCC based Project Build and Run under Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, cross-platform

I have been trying to port my C++ based mass data transport protocol project into visual studio 2010 with no success :(

The code I have been working on is fully compatible with Win based systems..well this is what my mentor also says :) But I have not been able to make the project build and run using my existing *.h & *.cpp files under VS 2010.

The Project basically is a API under which i have 4 separate applications. The hierarchy would be:

1. SRC FOLDER- all the *.h and respective *.cpp files
2. APP FOLDER- 4 applications (the API / library and some *.h files to be available before linking such as the final dll file under SRC folder & the main header file under APP folder)

I do also have a makefile as when the project was developed on Linux platform but I have no idea how to implement the same on Visual Studio 2010

FYI: VS 2010 on compiling reports that there are missing header files such as `<cstdlib>`, `<unistd>` but my best bet is this is not the real prob. but the prob. lies in the way I make the project build itself. I don't know should I go with making a dynamic dll project for the main library and then make the 4 empty c++ projects inside that for the 4 respective applications..?

Cheers,
echo9

Comment: You'd should create 1 solution, and 5 projects within that solution , 1 project for the library and one for each application. Start with getting the library compiled. But what is the actual problem, the question seems quite general and broad ?

Comment: @nos thanks for replying so fast. The problem lies in the missing header files. I have already declared the required #ifndef WIN32 preprocs. but still don't know whats keeping VS 2010 to just throw up like 13 errors :(

Comment: unistd is not available on Windows, but cstdlib definitely should be there - are you compiling the code as C or C++?

Comment: @unapersson I am compiling the code in Visual C++ available under VS 2010 Pro. The code is actually a bit of mix (C and C++; major being C++) I have chosen an empty c++ project while creating a new project to get a compiler version of the lib first.. and still stuck on it :( And for unistd I have already defined something as: #ifndef WIN32
   #include <unistd.h>
#else
   #include <winsock2.h>
   #include <ws2tcpip.h>
#endif

Comment: guys I was able to resolve the previous errors but now I am facing a new one: "definition of dllimport static data member not allowed" What does that mean?

Comment: allright.. resolved the previous error as stated by me above^ but now comes another one:error FTK1011: could not create the new file tracking log file: "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\nux_2_win\app\CL.read.1.tlog. The file exists"

Comment: Guys.. its done! Thanks.. Dennis & unapersson for the help!

Comment: @echo9 - wanna mark my reply as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you parse the data that you need from the working .mak file that you used previously. Create an empty project & sln, then add the contents of the "src" by using "add->existing files" in the file menu.

At that point open up the project configuration settings and go through the C++ and linker settings one by one. At each step have a look at the linux .mak file and see that you are choosing equivalent options and path settings. In particular make sure that you add all of the necessary include paths to where your .h files are.

That's what I would do anyways... same process as porting forwards old MSVC4 .mak projects to a modern version.

Comment: allright..I'll give you the feedback asap. I just hope this time VS 2010 won't let me down

Comment: @echo9 - not sure what you mean by the "4 applications"... if they are libs (static or dll) then you just need to make sure that they are included in the linker settings. If you need to compile them then add them as separate projects in the same solution and setup dependencies at the solution level settings.

Comment: By mentioning "4 applications" I mean that there are 4 different applications which will use the final compiled library & the main header file lib.h under src folder at the time of linking (in case of WIN..it would be lets suppose a lib.dll file; as on Linux it was a *.lib file; now thats dynamic library in both cases ain't it?)

Comment: @Dennis I got 9 errors while compiling saying like unistd.h, sys/time.h, netdb.h, sys/socket.h  are not available. What to do..?

Comment: So the main project that you are looking to port to VC2010 is producing a .lib (used for linking) and a .dll (used at runtime) that is being used by the 4 applications that you are talking about? If that is the case you do not need to worry about it unless you are compiling the applications yourself. If they are just .exes that use the .dll then you do not need to do anything with them except make the .dll available to them at runtime.

If you do need to compile these applications, then you should do as I suggest above and put them in the same solution as different .vcprojs.

Comment: @echo9 - you need to make them available. As unaperson said above, unistd.h is not a windows standard header file. If you need to include non-standard files then you'll need to provide them yourself and tell the compiler where they are. Ask your mentor about it, as (s)he seems to think that the project is portable.

Comment: @ Dennis by mentioning *.lib that is in Linux environment when the library got compiled and for windows the equivalent is a *.dll I guess..? Thats what I meant.. sorry if I got you confused above ^ :D

Comment: @echo9 - In windows you will generate a .lib only for a statically linked library. For a dynamically linked library you get a .dll. A statically linked library basically means that you link the actual functionality into your .exe. A dynamically linked library means that you tell the linker that it can expect the functionality at runtime, in which case the functionality will be provided by the .dll. In BOTH cases the linker will link to the .lib file.

Comment: @Dennis hehe... allright seems like we both were saying right about lib and dll stuff although lib on linux and lib on windows.. :) mind opener for me overall~

Comment: @Dennis well I guess i will go with a dynamically link lib. for the purpose. but what about the errors about the headers..? How can I somehow suppress them?

Comment: @ Dennis uhh..I guess its not good to say this but I can't help it now seeing all those errors going up and down the output window.. but can you import the project in a visual studio project/solution for me? I can provide you with the source code.

Comment: @echo9 - No way am I going to do your job for you. You have ALL of the information that you need to do this. You do not need to suppress ANYTHING. Just find the headers and put them in the right places or add their paths to the list of include directories.

Comment: good stuff. Come back with specific questions if you are stuck, but try it yourself first.... nevermind, I see you've managed it... well done.